# Swift - Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'

Tags: swift

Not really understanding why this isn't working. I'm pretty new to the Swift world.

The error I'm getting is `Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'`

Could anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error? Do I need to convert the String to a Double or is there something else I'm totally missing? Again I'm new to Swift.

Comment: All message, message1, etc should be Int.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to convert the String to a Double?

Yes, that's basically it.

You must declare first a variable to accumulate all the inputs:

```
var inputs = [Double]()
```

Observe that I'm declaring an array of `Double` because that's what we are interested in.

Then, each time you ask the input, convert the obtained `String` to `Double` and store it in your array:

```
print("Please enter a temperature\t", terminator: "")
var message : String = readLine()!
let value : Double = Double(message)!
inputs.append(value)
```

Finally, check all the accumulated values in `inputs` (you got this part right):

```
for value in inputs {
    // value is already a Double
    if value >= 80 { 
        message = "hot!"
    }
    // etc.
}
```

I suggest researching how to convert to `Double` with error checking (i.e. how to detect "100 hot!" and ignore it because can't be converted).

Also, consider using a loop to read the values.

Comment: Don’t force unwrap your optionals. Use the nil coalescing operator and provide a default value. `?? ""` for String or `?? 0` for a numeric type

Comment: @LeoDabus I respected the original code as much as possible. The OP seems a total beginner and I didn't want to rewrite everything creating further confussion. Also, force unwrapping in an example that is not about optionals is totally valid IMHO, but it wasn't the case.